# OpenGL - Creation of VAO inside the rendering loop is good option?

Tags: c++, opengl, vbo, vao

I've paste a pseudo-code for what I have design in OpenGL.

**What I have:**

- On the function createVAOs() bellow, I created all the vertices (VBO) that I want, and the indices (EBO) to draw some nice squares.
- Then, on the main loop, in the function draw_textures() I bind the texture and draw an element with a texture to the vertices on the VBO.

**What I want:**

- Now I want to change dynamically the VAO. Let's imagine: I want to add a new texture to a specific triangle, or even delete some triangles on my VAO. But since the VAO was created before the loop, I have a problem... I don't know if it is "wise" or "optimized" to create the VAO's everytime inside the loop..

**My question:**

*- Is wise to place the creation of the VAO (VBO and EBO) inside the rendering loop? If not, what is the best solution for this?*

Consider my pseudo-code bellow:

```
int main (void)
{
    //Init OpenGL, Glew,etc

    //Load Shaders

    createVAOs(); //triangles vertices (VBO) and indices (EBO)

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(m_window)) //the LOOP!
    {
        //updateEvents ();

        //use shaders

        //bindVAO();

            /*createVAOs();*/ //<---- is this wise??
            draw_textures();

        //freeVAO

        //swapBuffers
    }

    return 0;
}

void draw_textures()
{
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture.id());
    glDrawElements (GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, (void*)(0));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To delete (or insert) the triangles you change the VBO data and update it through one of the many ways to do it (eg. `glBufferData` or `glSubBufferData`).

I don't see the point with the texture since it's bound outside the VAO creation. If you need different textures for different triangles then you have two options:

- bind multiple textures and pass which one to the shader as an attribute of the vertex
- split the VBO in multiple VBOs (with respective VAO) and draw them one by one (of course you need to group them by shaders/texture since you want to minimize state changes).